# Printing when print server is offline

Tags: windows, printing, print-server

We are searching for a way to allow client computers utilizing a print server (2012 R2+) to still print even when the print server is down? It seems that all jobs try to get sent to the network printer via print server for every job. We have tried playing with "render on client computers" setting but didn't help.

Comment: If your printing is so important that you can't sustain any downtime, you should cluster your print servers.

Answer (score 0):

> We are searching for a way to allow client computers utilizing a print
>   server (2012 R2+) to still print even when the print server is down?
>   It seems that all jobs try to get sent to the network printer via
>   print server for every job. We have tried playing with "render on
>   client computers" setting but didn't help.

Rendering the print job on the clients doesn't change the fact that the clients have to actually print through the print server. If you want clients to be able to print when the print server is down then the clients need to connect directly to the printer.

Client-side rendering allows the clients to "hold" the print job in the event that the print server is offline but in order to actually print, the print server needs to be online and available to the clients.